# Conditional List in ReactJS Based On State

Tags: reactjs

I am pretty new to React JS and I am just wondering how I can filter what my component renders based on the state of my prop.

So I have the following component that allows me to select a certain brand and store it as a prop:

```
var React = require('react');
import Select from 'react-select';

class VehicleSelect extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { brandSelect: ""};

  }

  _onChange(value) {
      //console.log(value) - just to see what we recive from <Select />
      this.setState({brandSelect: value}, () => {
          console.log(this.state.brandSelect);
      });
    }

  render() {
    var options = [
      { value: 'Volkswagen', label: 'Volkswagen' },
      { value: 'SEAT', label: 'SEAT' },
      { value: 'SKODA', label: 'SKODA' }
    ];


    return (
      <Select
          name="form-field-name"
          value={this.state.brandSelect}
          options={options}
          placeholder="Select a brand"
          searchable={false}
          onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}
      />
    )
  }
};

// Export our component
export default VehicleSelect;
```

This component works as expected however I am having issues when it comes to taking the `brandSelect` prop and conditionally deciding what my component should render.

Here is my details component:

```
var React = require('react');
import { If, Then, Else } from 'react-if';
import VehicleSelect from './vehicle-select.js';
// Vehicle Description Component

const VehicleDetail = (props) => {
  return (
  <If condition={ this.state.brandSelect === props.vehicle.brand.name }>
    <div className="col-flex-md-3 col-flex-sm-4 col-flex-xs-6 col-flex-media-query">
      <div className="vehicle-container">
        <img src={"https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pulman-vw-images/uploads/images/thumbnails/" + props.vehicle.offers[0].image.name} />
        <h4 className="vehicle-title">
          {props.vehicle.model.name}
        </h4>
        <div className="row-flex">
          <div className="col-flex-xs-12 btn-container">
            <a href={"http://pulman" + props.vehicle.brand.name + ".co.uk/new/cars/" + props.vehicle.slug} target="_blank" className="learn-more-btn">Learn More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </If>

  );
};

// Export our component
export default VehicleDetail;
```

As you can see it constructs a HTML container with data. I have also added a conditional statement (react-if on GitHub) to try and render data that matches the option that was selected in my `VehicleSelect` component however this doesn't seem to work. I get the following error:

`Warning: There is an internal error in the React performance measurement code. Did not expect componentDidUpdate timer to start while render timer is still in progress for another instance.`

Here is my component that iterates over my `VehicleDetail` component and supplies data to it:

```
var React = require('react');
// Vehicle List Componen
import VehicleDetail from './vehicle-detail.js';

// Create our component
const VehicleList = (props) => {
  // Just add props.vehicle to access API data instead of static
  const RenderedVehicles = props.vehicles.map(vehicle =>
    <VehicleDetail key={vehicle.slug} vehicle={vehicle} />
  );

  return (
    <div className="row-flex center-xs">
      {RenderedVehicles}
    </div>
  );
};

// Export our component
export default VehicleList;
```

So my question is where am I going wrong? As I am new to ReactJS I am unsure how I can render components based on the state that has been selected. All I am trying to do is show data that matches the `brandSelect` prop in my VehicleSelect component. If the brandSelect prop is equals `""` then I would like to render all of the data that is mapped in my `VehicleList` component.

Thanks

Comment: Are you rendering `VehicleDetail` as a child component of `VehicleSelect` and passing the brandSelect down as a prop?

Comment: Whatever passes `vehicles` to `<VehicleList>` should filter `vehicles` before passing that array in as a prop. So `<VehicleDetails>` and `<VehicleList>` don't 'know' what the current selection is, they just render what they're given.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this.state.brandSelect  in the Details component
Since your details component is setup and brandselect is present in the parent component too