# Ordering list from conditionally rendered items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using this documentation https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd to add drag and drop functionality to my app.

Working tutorial version: https://codepen.io/c15mnw/pen/wXyZrW?editors=0010

My rendition- https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ef9gan

I've used most of the source code, but I've run into a stopping point since my app doesn't use fixed data like the example, I'm having trouble getting the list items to move into place.

My app uses conditional rendering to show append fields onto the current view based on whatever button click so there is conditional rendering in what should be in the drag and drop items.

I am at the point that I can drag individual input fields (clicking and holding the green area) but I can't drop them into place/change order.

Looking at my code, I believe that the problem is either in how I am mapping the data in `return` statement or in the way `state` was set in my application.

Tutorial code (omitted in my version):

```
const getItems = (count: number): Item[] =>
  Array.from({ length: count }, (v, k) => k).map(k => ({
    id: `item-${k}`,
    content: `item ${k}`
  }));
```

which is then passed into state...

```
    this.state = {
      items: getItems(6),
    };
```

instead my state is passed like this in `components/InputShow.jsx`

```
    this.state = {
      items: [this.props.node]
    };
    this.onDragEnd = this.onDragEnd.bind(this);
  }
```

I've taken a look at a few S/O answers including [Conditionally render list with Higher Order Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42080459/conditionally-render-list-with-higher-order-component) & [Conditional List in ReactJS Based On State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38586246/conditional-list-in-reactjs-based-on-state) among others but I didn't think the pertained to my situation.

I'm still pretty new to React, so I'm not sure exactly where I'm going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Very hard to follow all this code, please try creating a minimal example of your problem, refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)